# Identifying a set with brown curved top and circular gray pieces on the sides

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

[image]

Came partially assembled with a bulk used lot. The color scheme makes me think it could be from a Star Wars set. It doesn't have any minifigs but I found other loose pieces with imperial logo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is from

- LEGO Star Wars Set 9491-1 , **Geonosian Cannon**.

[image]

Comment: It most definitely is. I found some of the rest in loose pieces that where harder to identify. No minifigs though.